# ScopedCssBaseline in material ui overrides box-sizing of component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make use of [ScopedCssBaseline](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/#scoping-on-children), but its behavior is different from CssBaseline.
ScopeCssBaseline add styles to input:

```css
.MuiScopedCssBaseline-root *, .MuiScopedCssBaseline-root *::before, .MuiScopedCssBaseline-root *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

which overrides `box-sizing: content-box` of `.MuiInputBase-input`, so inputs look bad.

How I can scope css baseline so that with behaviour similar to CssBaseline?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-kf8iy?file=/demo.tsx